# Beginner - where to place SCSS files in a Magento structure

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend

I'm a FE devleoper just beginning to work with an existing **Magento 1.8 CE** website from a git repository. I find it difficult to understand all the rules, but working my way through it.

One of the first things I want to change is switch to using **COMPASS/SASS** - installing and using **GruntJS** alongside.

Can I simply install Grunt using the default dirctories without irritating Magento?
Where can I place the SCSS files that will then be compiled into the css files in `/skin/frontend/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME/css/`?

Could I simply create and use e.g. a directory named `/skin/frontend/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME/source/`, or will Magento be irritated by that?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm really unsure about the complex directory structure and Magento's coding by convention rules and don't want to make a bad decision when introducing GruntJS and COMPASS.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently contain all our un-processed CSS outside of the Magento filesystem, so our project structure would look like this:

```
/project_root
    - scss/
    - magento/
    - Gruntfile.js
```

When `grunt sass` is run from `project_root` the compiled css is saved to the correct skin path (`magento/skin/frontend/package/default/css/`) inside Magento.

This way you don't have to worry about updating the Magento filesystem and serving *.sass files to the internet.

Your `Gruntfile.js` could look something like this with the `grunt-contrib-sass` plugin from https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-sass

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            magento: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'magento/skin/frontend/package/default/css/style.css': 'frontend/scss/core.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
};
```

**EDIT**

If I was unable to modify the project root, I would add a new directory called `scss` to the skin path (`/skin/frontend/package/default/scss`) and store the scss framework here.

Then add `Gruntfile.js` to the root of Magento and compile the `sccs`  here: `/skin/frontend/package/default/css`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good example! Thank you. Another question then: Could I as well place my scss directory right in the magento root - in your example this would then be /project_root/magento/scss ?
In our project unfortunately the magento installation itself is the project root...

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of why you'd need to worry about the specific folders you place your files in, is if you're using one of Magento's convenience methods for loading CSS, JS, etc (ie. `$this->getSkinUrl()`)

Creating your own folder under `/skin` will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still interested in how to do this I've created a Magento Boilerplate that does just this. Just drag and drop then run the grunt commands to watch.

https://github.com/jasonalvis/magento-boilerplate

Thanks.